# Template files for Site 2 in MSM

Tags: templates, multi-site-manager

Pretty basic question here, but this is my first MSM build.

What is the proper template path/location for Site 2 in MSM?

Should they be within the Site 2 file structure, or should they be with the default site file structure?

Currently, only `admin.php` and `index.php` exist within the site 2 file structure.

Comment: if you want to talk about this - give me a call in the evening or we can chat at the next Toronto Meetup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSM should store everything about the site in the default site installation, except for the index.php & admin.php files in the 2nd site that route requests into the install.

You may be able to specify a different path for the template location within the Site 2 context in the CP, but all of your other paths (add-ons, etc) are going to point to the Site 1 install. Makes sense to keep all your code centralized and just see the template files in different subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can basically put them wherever you want so long as you set the appropriate template path.

You may want them stored under the "main" MSM installation or you may prefer, as I do, to keep them within each site's directory.

As an example I have an MSM installation running 8 sites and the directories are set up like so (missing out some of the directories for the sake of brevity);

```
htdocs
    'main' site
        index.php
        admin.php
        eesystem
            expressionengine
                templates
                    default_site (templates for the main site)
        images
        etc
    site2
        index.php
        admin.php
        templates
        images
    site3
        index.php
        admin.php
        templates
        images
    site4
        index.php
        admin.php
        templates
        images

and so on...
```

Comment: I was just going to post this exact answer as this is exactly how I do it too.

Comment: Is there a way to set individual MSM tmpl_file_basepath's in the config – or does it need to be via the CP? I've taken on an old EE2 site and this would be my prefered method... but I'm trying to limit DB changes.